# How to store user date in Pinia Store? With @sidebase/nuxt-auth 0.6.0 and "local" provider?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, pinia, nuxt-auth

I'm rebuilding legacy Nuxt 2, Vue 2, Vuex code using Nuxt 3, Vue 3 and Pinia. I'm using @sidebase/nuxt-auth 0.6.0 (beta) "local" provider for the user authorisation.

I am able to login/logout the user etc. **My problem is with getting access to the user data, I want to store this in a useUserStore (Pinia)**, so that I'm able to process the user permissions inside my store and provide getters for these permissions.

**I have tried the following:**

This is my Pinia Store:

```
const { signIn, data } = useAuth();

export const useUserStore = defineStore("user", () => {
  const user = ref({});

  async function loginUser(credentials: any) {
    try {
      await signIn({
        email_address: credentials.email_address,
        password: credentials.password,
      });
      console.log(data);
    } catch (e) {}
  }
  return { user, loginUser };
});
```

**When I console log the useAuth Data, nothing gets logged..**

I have also tried doing:

```
const { signIn, data } = useAuth();

export const useUserStore = defineStore("user", () => {
  const user = ref({});

  function loginUser(credentials: any) {
    try {
      signIn({
        email_address: credentials.email_address,
        password: credentials.password,
      }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
    } catch (e) {}
  }
  return { user, loginUser };
});
```

but that also doesn't work.

**How can I set my user ref with the useAuth data? My endgoal is to have the user info available in my Pinia Store.**

Answer (score 1):

You wont see output from your console logs if `signIn` function is producing an error, the code will escape before executing `console.log` in both your examples, and you have no visibility of your errors because you have basically silenced them by doing `catch (e) {}`.

First I would start with modifying `catch` to `catch (e) { console.dir(e) }` and ensure its not erroring out before trying to debug this any further.